# Keeping high scores in a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm quite new to Python. I would like to keep a high score in Python, and only write the new players name. I would like to implement this in a larger program, but I can't quite get this logic down yet.

How do you handle an old player setting a better score than before?
How do you deal with two players with the same name having scores?

```
save_name = raw_input('Enter your name. ').title()
save_score = raw_input('Enter your score. ')

text_file = open("highscores.txt", "a")
text_file.write("\n" + save_name + ' has a score of ' + save_score + "\n")
text_file.close()

print ("\n")
text_file = open("highscores.txt", "r")
whole_thing = text_file.read()
print (whole_thing)
text_file.close()
```

Comment: What part is not working?

Comment: Only writing new users' names, and not writing their name and highscore to a new line.

Comment: @techteej the line `text_file.readlines(save_name)` does not write anything, if fact, I think, it will fail there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your goal is to read in the high scores and only add those scores that were made by a new player. If so the questions you have to ask are:

- How do you handle an old player setting a better score than before?
- How do you deal with two players with the same name having scores?
- How do you want to display your high scores?

Personally I wouldn't do this in a text file, but write it in a dictionary and `pickle` it.

```
import pickle

high_scores = {"Adam Smith": 65536, "John Doe": 10000}
with open("highscores.pkl","wb") as out:
    pickle.dump(high_scores, out)
```

Then when you have to write a new score:

```
import collections

Score = collections.namedtuple("Score", ["name","score"]) # just to make things easy
new_score = Score("Joe Schmoe",12000)

with open("highscores.pkl","rb") as in_:
    high_scores = pickle.load(in_)
if new_scores.name not in high_scores:
    high_scores[new_scores.name] = new_scores.score
with open("highscores.pkl","wb") as out:
    pickle.dump(high_scores, out)
```

This will also help when displaying high scores, because you can do something like:

```
print("{{TITLE:^{PAGE_WIDTH}}}".format(PAGE_WIDTH=80).format(TITLE="HIGH SCORES"))
print("-" * 80)
for name,score in high_scores.items():
    print("{{name:>{col_width}}} | {{score:<{col_width}}}".format(col_width=(80-3)//2).format(name=name, score=score))
```

The formatting in this bit is a bit overkill for your use case, but if you need to display this on a smaller screen (with fewer columns per page) you'll thank me later! Replace all the `80`s with a constant and put your columns-per-page in the constant, something like `MAX_WIDTH` maybe. Easy peasy.

Comment: How would I accept user input on this? To add to the score?

Comment: @techteej I would assume you'd already have the user input before your game starts, and your game would use this as a driver to power high scores. If not, then ignore everything I wrote about `collections.namedtuple` and just use `new_score = (raw_input("Enter your name ").title(), int(raw_input("Enter your score ")))`

Comment: @techteej however if I were designing something like this I would create a user, allow them to set a password, saved the salted+hashed password into a database somewhere and use the DB key to store their high score. Wrapping it all up into one SQL DB is probably saner.

Comment: Adding the input statements brings up the following error: 'Tuple' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: @techteej right because the rest of my code uses object notation (`new_score.name`) because I used a `collections.namedtuple`. If you don't know how to use those, you'll have to use indexing (`new_score[0]`) to access the items inside your tuple. Or else just do `new_name = raw_input("Enter your name ").title(); new_score = int(raw_input("Enter your score "))` and change the rest of the code to match.

Comment: @techteej regardless I will leave it to you to figure out how to handle a higher score coming in than what is recorded.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `text_file.readlines(save_name)` will throw a `TypeError` because `save_name` is not an integer. See [the readlines documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines). Second of all, this line will not do anything as you are not assigning a variable to the return value of `readlines`. I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve here. This part of your code is working fine:

```
save_name = raw_input('Enter your name. ').title()
save_score = raw_input('Enter your score. ')

text_file = open("highscores.txt", "a")
text_file.write("\n" + save_name + ' has a score of ' + save_score + "\n")
text_file.close()
```

It will correctly write to the `highscores.txt` file.
If you want to print the contents of the highscores file, the last part of your code is doing that just fine.

```
text_file = open("highscores.txt", "r")
whole_thing = text_file.read()
print (whole_thing)
text_file.close()
```

The part in between these two quoted  block is probably obsolete and/or we need a better specification of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Using your code I've made some changes to check first the high score and only add a new score if the user beats the last score:

```
save_name = raw_input('Enter your name. ').title()
save_score = raw_input('Enter your score. ')

last_high_score = 0

#look for highscore
try:
    text_file = open("highscores.txt", "r")
    for line in text_file.readlines():
        #you can use regular expressions here to simplify the lookup

        #get the las part of the score assuming the pattern:
        #"text[ has a score of] score"

        line_parts = line.split(" has a score of ")
        if len(line_parts) > 1:
            #removing the end \n character
            line_parts = line_parts[-1].split("\n")
            score = line_parts[0]
            #compare the last high score with the newest
            if score.isdigit() and int(score) > last_high_score:
                last_high_score = int(score)
except Exception, e:
    #the first time trows an exception because the high score file does not exist
    pass

#check if there is a new high score
if int(save_score) > last_high_score:
    text_file = open("highscores.txt", "a")
    text_file.write("\n"+save_name+' has a score of '+save_score+"\n")
    text_file.close()

print ("\n")
text_file = open("highscores.txt", "r")
whole_thing = text_file.read()
print (whole_thing)
text_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ave_name = raw_input('Enter your name. ').title()
save_score = raw_input('Enter your score. ')

last_high_score = 0

#look for highscore
try:
    text_file = open("highscores.txt", "r")
    for line in text_file.readlines():
        #you can use regular expressions here to simplify the lookup

        #get the las part of the score assuming the pattern:
        #"text[ has a score of] score"

        line_parts = line.split(" has a score of ")
        if len(line_parts) > 1:
            #removing the end \n character
            line_parts = line_parts[-1].split("\n")
            score = line_parts[0]
            #compare the last high score with the newest
            if score.isdigit() and int(score) > last_high_score:
                last_high_score = int(score)
except Exception, e:
    #the first time trows an exception because the high score file           
     pass
#unban user14762509 moderator fags


 #check if there is a new high score
if int(save_score) > last_high_score:
       text_file = open("highscores.txt", "a")
         text_file.write("\n"+save_name+' has a score of        '+save_score+"\n")
     text_file.close()

print ("\n")
text_file = open("highscores.txt", "r")
whole_thing = text_file.read()
  print (whole_thing)
text_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ONLY write the user's name, and not their high score, couldn't you just change this:

text_file.write("\n" + save_name + ' has a score of ' + save_score + "\n")

To this:

text_file.write("\n" + save_name +  "\n")

Comment: read in the high scores and only add those scores that were made by a new player

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure does this helps

```
import time
import operator
startTime=time.time()
x=input('testonly')



endTime=time.time()
userscore=int(endTime-startTime)


scorelist=[]
beathighscore=False

scorefile=open('score.txt','r')
score=scorefile.readlines()
scorefile.close

for line in score:
    scorelist.append(line.strip())
if len(score)!=0:
    for item in scorelist:
        oldscore=((item[0])[1])
        oldscore=int(oldscore)
else:
    oldscore=float('inf')
if userscore<oldscore:
    print("you beat the highscore")
    username=input("pls enter ur name")
    newscore=(username,userscore)
    scorelist.append(newscore)


with open('score.txt',"w") as writescore:
    for item in scorelist:
        writescore.write(''.join(str(item))+'\n')
writescore.close
```

Comment: I'm trying to create a code for it to keep scores in a text file and it'll keep on updating if the user beat the top 10 high score